# c++ function making for a file reading through delimiter but in different style

Tags: c++, function

I want to make a parser , that read a line from a txt file file like:

```
INDORE|NJ|201568|A|
UJJAIN|AB|3458|B|
```

is their any inbuilt function that read one line at a time...
catch values in correspoding variable, through a format specifier.. but separate values by `|` *delimiter*.

```
parser(str,'|',"%S|%S|%S|%S",location,name,phno,tok);
```

`location`,`name`,...etc are variables.

I found a function in matlab "**strread**", that does this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `str`is a stream, since all your variables appear to be strings, you can simple use `std::getline` with `'|'` as delimiter.

```
std::getline(str, location, '|');
std::getline(str, name, '|');
std::getline(str, phno, '|');
std::getline(str, tok, '|');
```

You could even wrap this into a variadic template function which takes all parameters you want to read into.

```
void readParams(std::istream& stream, char delim)
{
}

template<typename ... Tail>
void readParams(std::istream& stream, char delim, std::string& string, Tail& ... t)
{
  std::getline(stream, string, delim);
  readParams(stream, delim, t ...);
}
```

This function can then be called as such:

```
readParams(str, '|', location, name, phno, tok);
```

If you are restricted to using a compiler without variadic templates, you can still add a few overloads for the number of arguments that you want, and replace them by a true variadic template at a later stage.

Comment: Beaten to it by 7 seconds ... :P

Comment: i want to make a function for my all different file, which takes sometimes space as token, comma, as token,. i already used this getline function for my file parsing, but now i have to bind it in one function.

Comment: what if my variables are all of different kind.. like one is interger, and another char,etc

Answer (score 0):

Might be little bit more comfy... the input file is a|b|c|

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1 [80] = {0};
  char str2 [80] = {0};
  char str3 [80] = {0};
  FILE * pFile;

  pFile = fopen ("a.txt","r");
  fscanf(pFile, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%[^|]|", str1, str2, str3); 
  fclose (pFile);
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: I did misread exclamation mark for pipe..

---

the input file is a|b|2|

```
  char str1 [80] = {0};
  char str2 [80] = {0};
  int i;
  fscanf(pFile, "%[^|]|%[^|]|%d|", str1, str2, &i);
```

Comment: what if my variables are all of different kind.. like one is interger, and another char,etc